# почему компилятор не видит .find() на массива экземпляров класса

Tags: typescript

Изучаю дженерики. В коде:

```
class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
  private _data: KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] = [];
  add(key: TKey, value: TValue): void {
    const entry = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>();
    entry.key = key;
    entry.value = value;
    this._data.push(entry);
  }
  get(key: TKey): TValue | null {
    return this._data.find(el => el.key === key); // <-- 
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "es5", "es6", "es7", "es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "es2018"]
  },
...
}
```

Error:(70, 23) TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'KeyValuePair[]'.

Почему эта ошибка, ведь объявил то я массив?

Comment: что у вас в свойстве `lib` в `tsconfig`'е?

Comment: У меня в tsconfig такого свойства нет.

Comment: [почему?](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#lib-option)

Answer (score -2):

В вашем примере не определен тип `KeyValuePair`.
И несоответствует тип результата метода  `get`.

```
class KeyValuePair<Tkey, Tvalue> {
  key: Tkey;
  value: Tvalue;
}
class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
  private _data: KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] = [];
  add(key: TKey, value: TValue): void {
    const entry = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>();
    entry.key = key;
    entry.value = value;
    this._data.push(entry);
  }
  get(key: TKey): TValue | null {
    const result = this._data.find(el => el.key === key);
    if (result) {
      return result.value;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

let dict = new Dictionary<string, number>();

dict.add('a', 1);

console.log(dict.get('a'));
```